# How do I filter text ( password ) in the Nodejs Express logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, express, passwords

I'm currently using `app.use(express.logger('dev'))` for logging and need to be able to filter sensitive text sent via HTTP request parameters.

I can see the sensitive text:

```
/users/sessions?username=test&password=test
```

I want the log entry like:

```
/users/sessions?username=test&password=[FILTERED]
```

Comment: You may want to consider using `POST`, sending these values in the request's body (and using `bodyParser()` and `req.body` to retrieve them). Then, they won't be cached by the browser and Express doesn't log the body.

Comment: POST requests aren't logged as well?

Comment: Sorry. `POST` requests are still logged. But, their bodies won't be included in that. Just URL path, headers, responding status, etc.